# Why are some of my own Facebook comments not deletable?

Tags: facebook

Have a look at the following screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

It seems I cannot delete some of my own comments. If simply displays a *None* option, does anyone know how to delete it anyway?

Comment: Do they have a reply?

Comment: Possibly the original post was deleted,  causing the system to have no delete option for you, because there is nothing there. Check.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to find the permalink to it by hovering over the timestamp, from there you should be able to see an option to delete it.